# Let's get critical: Jan 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [German Language Stack Exchange](http://german.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://german.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Warum hat »nächtlich« einen Umlaut und »weihnachtlich« keinen?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8763/warum-hat-nachtlich-einen-umlaut-und-weihnachtlich-keinen)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Can "als" be used to refer to extended periods of time?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8612/can-als-be-used-to-refer-to-extended-periods-of-time)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Hin and her prepositional contractions](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8491/hin-and-her-prepositional-contractions)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [A joke from “The Magic Mountain”/“Der Zauberberg” translated into English?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8697/a-joke-from-the-magic-mountain-der-zauberberg-translated-into-english)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Das Genus von »Teil«: der oder das?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8715/der-genus-von-teil-der-oder-das)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Does "paar" still mean "two items"? Words that have lost their original meaning](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8555/does-paar-still-mean-two-items-words-that-have-lost-their-original-meaning)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Reflexive "treffen" when planning to meet someone?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8486/reflexive-treffen-when-planning-to-meet-someone)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Was ist ein "Kurverein"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8656/was-ist-ein-kurverein)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Zusammen oder getrennt Schreiben von "durchzusprechen"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8510/zusammen-oder-getrennt-schreiben-von-durchzusprechen)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Sprachlicher Vergleich](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8536/sprachlicher-vergleich)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

Answer (score 3):

[Diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8510/zusammen-oder-getrennt-schreiben-von-durchzusprechen) ist meiner Meinung nach ein Duplikat von [dieser](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6421/zusammenschreiben-von-infinitiv-mit-zu?lq=1).

Wenn man nach durchzusprechen googelt, findet man erstere, wenn man allgemein nach Zusammenschreibung von Infinitiven googelt, findet man letztere (was ich eigentlich auch gut so finde). Nur dass bei der ersten (spezieller klingenden) Frage eine sehr allgemeine, gut zusammengefasste Antwort folgt und es bei der zweiten (allgemeiner klingenden) Frage eigentlich nur um "durcharbeiten" geht und die Antworten dementsprechend knapper ausfallen und die Gesamterklärung auf die Frage und die Antworten verteilt ist.

Habe die beiden Fragen jetzt mal verlinkt. Wenn einer der Moderatoren Lust hat, könnte man die beiden Fragen vielleicht irgendwie zusammenbasteln. Insbesondere auch, weil ich vermute, dass die zweite Frage öfter gefunden werden wird als die erste.

Comment: Good catch :) The specific question is now closed as a dupe of the more general question on that topic. Please note that [Meta posts should always be in English](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/325/please-use-english-on-the-meta-site).

Comment: @Takkat: I'm sorry, I get completely mixed up with languages on this site, half of the time I don't even notice which language I'm using.  But since the matter is cleared now I won't translate my post.