# Do the current statistics say that we need to increase the daily question rate from 5.1 to 15 in order to leave the beta?

Tags: discussion

See the current [statistics of the GLU](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18413/german-language). Currently we are rated as *excellent* in all aspects but:

```
                  Results      Vs              Remark
Questions         5.1/day            15 questions per day on average is a healthy beta
Answer ratio      2.4/day            2.5 answers per question is good, only 1 answer per question needs some work
```

- Does it mean that the 15 questions per day rate should be achieved before we leave the beta phase?
- If not (already partially answered in comments) Can somebody state in numbers what's missing for us to leave this phase?

Comment: Very briefly: No. Those are not all requirements to leave beta (others are, e.g., a robustly growing community, as I have gathered from other posts). Also, we do not need to excel in all of these aspects. Just have a looked at the “end of beta” statistics of some [graduated proposals](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=launched).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Strange, GLU's numbers are generally better than other grauduated proposals. What's missing?

Comment: As I said, a robustly growing community. This has been stated by SE managers on some meta posts or blog entries, which I cannot find right now.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Do we have access to a graph of the size of the community/day(bzw. month)?

Comment: @c.p. you might find some query in [the stack exchange data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/german/queries)

Comment: One thing I've noticed is that since a certain member left and took his questions with him, the questions/day has plummeted.

Comment: @thekeyofgb who? I didn't notice that. I mean, I thought the question would remain there for ever, even if one deletes the account. [For instance this question](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2540/is-there-a-rule-which-preposition-to-use-for-a-place).

Comment: @c.p. I meant more like they stopped asking questions rather than remove

Comment: @thekeyofgb Oh, I see. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are doing quite well in most of the statistics seen in Area51 but there is room for improvements.

- The rate of question/day always was low except few weeks when questions from single users pushed up this value.

  *This also tells us that it is not so much the number what counts but the overall contributing users, which at times are very few (if any).*
- The answers/question rate is okay but sadly its declining.

  *It will therefore certainly do no harm to encourage people to give more than one answer to a question as this makes the essence of all SE sites: choose a "best" answer by counting votes.*

More than these statistics I am concerned about the low community contributions to site issues.

Fortunately we now do have a solid base of high rep users to be able to perform "Community Moderation" (i.e. closing and reopening posts, approving edits, improving posts). Thats great, and it is a good step in the right direction.

But the contributions to Meta (where we shape our site) is far too low to proof that we have a lively and caring base of users. We still need to define our scope as can be seen from recent Meta posts but alas there is so little contribution to these posts, so little discussion, not even votes, to indicate that people really care.

Contributions to quality measures such as the [site-self-evaluations](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/614/lets-get-critical-jan-2014-site-self-evaluation) we already had was low too.

In addition to Meta we should also heavily use [our chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/499/german-language) as a fine place to discuss issues with the site, topicness of questions, wishes for changes, and more. These discussions there could eventually lead to valuable Meta posts, but this only rarely happens.

So in summary apart from statistics displayed in Area51 I believe we still need a lot of work done on the extent of community contributions to this site matters.

Comment: I am not that concerned about the answers/question rate (and hopefully neither is the Stack Exchange staff), since some questions just have a very clear answer that is obvious to native speakers.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that main points have been mentioned by Takkat and Wrzlprmft but I'd really like to repeat that we need to focus on having more members in our community who contribute and put in their opinions regularly.

We do have quite many visitors a day, but still only few views and votes on each questions.

This site is currently run by about 30 members. We sometimes get new members, but loses others at the same time.

So, what I recommend is to find a way to establish more active users. Suggestions are welcome ;)